NEAT giving error after deleting all the population
I'm trying to build a NEAT trading environment but when I kill all the population for some conditions, it gives me this error and does not continue to evolve:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\TradEvolver\main.py", line 188, in <module>
    run("./config.txt")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\TradEvolver\main.py", line 186, in run
    winner = p.run(main, 1000)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\neat\population.py", line 94, in run
    if best is None or g.fitness > best.fitness:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1577, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Code:
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import neat

def calculate_profit(buy_price, sell_price, balance):
    c = 0.001
    profit = (sell_price - buy_price) / buy_price * balance - (balance * c)
    new_balance = balance + profit
    return new_balance

class Trader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 10000
        self.buy_price = 0
        self.since_last_transaction = 0
        self.consq = []
        self.consq2 = []

    def buy(self, buy_price):
        self.buy_price = buy_price

    def sell(self, sell_price):
        self.balance = calculate_profit(self.buy_price, sell_price, self.balance) 
        self.buy_price = 0


file = "./data/BTCUSDT_2015-01-01T00_00_00+00_00__2024-10-10T23_59_59+00_00.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TradEvolver - Evolution Tracker")

def on_close():
    if messagebox.askyesno("Exit Confirmation", "Are you sure that you want to close the program?"):
        root.quit()
        sys.exit()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)

traders = []

for i in range(10):
    traders.append(Trader())

close_data = []

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

balance_frame = tk.Frame(root)
balance_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

balance_labels = []

def update_plot():
    for close in df['close']:
        close_data.append(close)
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(close_data, color='blue')
        ax.set_title('TradEvolver - Evolution Tracker')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        ax.set_ylabel('Close Price')

        for i, trader in enumerate(traders):
            action = random.choice(['buy', 'sell', 'hold'])
            if action == 'buy' and trader.buy_price == 0 :
                trader.buy(close)
            elif action == 'sell' and trader.buy_price != 0:
                trader.sell(close)

            balance_labels[i].config(text=f"Balance: {trader.balance:.2f}")

        canvas.draw()
        #time.sleep(0.01)

def start_plotting():
    plot_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_plot)
    plot_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()

def main(genomes, config):
    nets = []
    ge = []
    traders = []

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        traders.append(Trader())
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)

    for trader in traders:
        label = tk.Label(balance_frame, text=f"Balance: {trader.balance:.2f}")
        label.pack()
        balance_labels.append(label)

    for x, close in enumerate(df['close']):
        close_data.append(close)
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(close_data, color='blue')
        ax.set_title('TradEvolver - Evolution Tracker')
        ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        ax.set_ylabel('Close Price')            
        
        canvas.draw()

        if x > 7 and len(traders) > 0:
            for i, trader in enumerate(traders):
                istooconseq = False

                ehe = 1 if close > df["close"][x - 7] else 0

                output = nets[i].activate((close, trader.buy_price, df["close"][x] - df["open"][x], df["volume"][x], ehe))
                action = output.index(max(output))

                if action == 0 and trader.buy_price == 0:  # Buy
                    trader.buy(close)
                    trader.since_last_transaction = 0
                    trader.consq2.append(0)
                elif action == 1: #Hold
                    trader.since_last_transaction += 1
                    trader.consq2.append(0)
                elif action == 2 and trader.buy_price != 0:  # Sell
                    trader.since_last_transaction = 0
                    trader.sell(close)
                    trader.consq2.append(1)
                else:
                    trader.consq2.append(0)
                    trader.since_last_transaction += 1

                if trader.buy_price != 0:
                    ge[i].fitness += ((df["close"] - df["open"])/df["open"])*100

                max_index, max_trader = max(enumerate(traders), key=lambda x: x[1].balance)

                #print(max_trader.balance, max_trader.since_last_transaction, max_trader.buy_price)
                if x > 150:
                    trader.consq = trader.consq2[x-150:x]
                    istooconseq = trader.consq.count(1) > 60
                    #print(trader.consq.count(1))

                if trader.since_last_transaction > 250 or trader.balance < 5500 or istooconseq:
                    traders.pop(i)
                    ge.pop(i)
                    nets.pop(i)

                    if trader.balance < 5500:
                        print("too low balance", i, trader.balance)
                    elif trader.since_last_transaction > 250:
                        print("not making trades", i, trader.since_last_transaction)
                    elif istooconseq:
                        print("too consequtive", i, trader.consq.count(1))

                istooconseq = False

            #   balance_labels[i].config(text=f"Balance: {trader.balance:.2f}")
            
            canvas.draw()

        if len(traders) == 0:
            break


def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 1000)

run("./config.txt")

config.txt:
[NEAT]
fitness_criterion     = max
fitness_threshold     = 2000
pop_size              = 200
reset_on_extinction   = True

[DefaultGenome]
# Diverse activation functions and higher mutation rates
activation_default      = tanh
activation_mutate_rate  = 0.3
activation_options      = tanh, relu, sigmoid, swish

# Aggregation to allow more advanced behaviors
aggregation_default     = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.1
aggregation_options     = sum, avg, max

# Expanded bias ranges with increased mutation flexibility
bias_init_mean          = 0.0
bias_init_stdev         = 2.0
bias_max_value          = 20.0
bias_min_value          = -20.0
bias_mutate_power       = 1.0
bias_mutate_rate        = 0.8
bias_replace_rate       = 0.3

# Stronger speciation configuration for improved species differentiation
compatibility_disjoint_coefficient = 1.2
compatibility_weight_coefficient   = 0.7

# Add/remove connections for deeper exploration of connectivity
conn_add_prob           = 0.5
conn_delete_prob        = 0.3

# Network depth increased with initial dense connections
enabled_default         = True
enabled_mutate_rate     = 0.05
feed_forward            = True
initial_connection      = full_direct

# Higher node mutation probability and additional hidden layers
node_add_prob           = 0.3
node_delete_prob        = 0.1

# Input-output configuration with additional hidden units for more complex trading actions
num_hidden              = 5
num_inputs              = 5
num_outputs             = 3

# Expanded range for node responses to adapt well to diverse scenarios
response_init_mean      = 1.0
response_init_stdev     = 0.5
response_max_value      = 10.0
response_min_value      = -10.0
response_mutate_power   = 0.7
response_mutate_rate    = 0.5
response_replace_rate   = 0.2

# Wider range of connection weights and higher mutation rates for flexibility
weight_init_mean        = 0.0
weight_init_stdev       = 1.5
weight_max_value        = 15.0
weight_min_value        = -15.0
weight_mutate_power     = 1.0
weight_mutate_rate      = 0.8
weight_replace_rate     = 0.3

[DefaultSpeciesSet]
compatibility_threshold = 3.5

[DefaultStagnation]
species_fitness_func = max
max_stagnation       = 30
species_elitism      = 3

[DefaultReproduction]
elitism            = 2
survival_threshold = 0.3

The thing that I didn't understand is I tested simular flippybird NEAT algorithm and when bird hits to pipe, it was killing the bird. Here's the code
import pygame
import random
import neat
import os
import time
pygame.font.init()

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))

STAT_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d  -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION

        else:
             if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]     
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 10

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.height = 0

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()

    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50, 450)
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
        win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))
        
    def collide(self, bird):
        bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
        top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
        bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

        top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
        bottom_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y))

        b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
        t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

        if t_point or b_point:
            return True

        return False

class Base:
    VEL = 5
    WIDTH = BASE_IMG.get_width()
    IMG = BASE_IMG

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = self.WIDTH

    def move(self):
        self.x1 -= self.VEL
        self.x2 -= self.VEL

        if self.x1 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x1 = self.x2 + self.WIDTH

        if self.x2 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x2 = self.x1 + self.WIDTH

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x1, self.y)) 
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x2, self.y))

def draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))

    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.draw(win)

    text = STAT_FONT.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
    win.blit(text, (WIN_WIDTH -10 - text.get_width(), 10))
    base.draw(win)

    for bird in birds:
        bird.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()

def main(genomes, config):
    nets = []
    ge = []
    birds = []

    for _, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        birds.append(Bird(230,350))
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)


    base = Base(730)
    pipes = [Pipe(600)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    score = 0

    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pipe_ind = 0

        if len(birds) > 0:
            if len(pipes) > 1 and birds[0].x > pipes[0].x + pipes[0].PIPE_TOP.get_width():
                pipe_ind = 1
        else:
            run = False
            break

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            output = nets[x].activate((bird.y, abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].height), abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                bird.jump()

        #bird.move()
        rem = []
        add_pipe = False

        for pipe in pipes:
            for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    birds.pop(x)
                    nets.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1

            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5

            pipes.append(Pipe(600))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 730 or bird.y < 0:
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)


        base.move()
        draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score)


def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)

    p = neat.Population(config)
    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config.txt")
    run(config_path)

Basically, I tried to implement same logic but it giving me error at my env and works perfectly for flippybird algorithm
